# $m+n+p = 2017$ Solve for $(x,y,z,t)$ $x+my+nz+pt =2018$

Tags: contest-math

$m, n,p \in \mathbb{N}^*$ such that $m+n+p = 2017$.

Find the values of $x,y,z,t$ Such that  $x+my+nz+pt =2018$
With $x,y,z,t \in \mathbb N^*$

**My Attempt:**

Im not sure if this solution is correct because it looks easy to me.

If we add a $1$ to the original equation:
$$1+1(m)+(1)n+(1)p=2018$$

And fron here, It’s easy to see that the only solution to the equation is $(x,y,z,t)=(1,1,1,1)$,
Given the fact that $(x,y,z,t) \in \mathbb N^*$  so they cannot equal to $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can formalize this by considering $x=1$ and $x\geq 2$ by observing that
$$x+m(y-1)+n(z-1)+p(t-1) + m + n+ p =2018 \\
\implies x+m(y-1)+n(z-1)+p(t-1) =1$$

$x=1$:
$$ m(y-1)+n(z-1)+p(t-1)=0 \\
\implies (y-1)=(z-1)=(t-1) = 0 \\
(y,z,t) = (1,1,1)
$$

$x\geq 2$:
$$ m(y-1)+n(z-1)+p(t-1)\lt 0 
$$
so at least one of $(y{-}1),(z{-}1),(t{-}1)$ is less than zero and the corresponding in  $y,z,t$ is not $\in \mathbb N^*$

For style you could perhaps define $y',z',t'\in \mathbb N_0$ to be the decremented versions of $y,z,t$

---

---

@zwim in comments points out that we can extend the initial reformulation:
\begin{align}
x+m(y-1)+n(z-1)+p(t-1) + m + n+ p &=2018 \\
\implies x+m(y-1)+n(z-1)+p(t-1) &=1 \\
\implies (x-1)+m(y-1)+n(z-1)+p(t-1) &=0 \\
\implies (x-1)=(y-1)=(z-1)=(t-1) &=0
\end{align}

giving us $(x,y,z,t) = (1,1,1,1)$ as stated.

Comment: Why separating in two cases ? I would state directly $(x-1)+m(y-1)+n(z-1)+p(t-1)=0\implies (x-1)=(y-1)=(z-1)=(t-1)=0$.

Comment: @zwim Yes, that works nicely. I just wanted to emphasize the lack of solutions with larger $x$.

Comment: @joffan did you knew about the answer before or this is the first time you see this problem?

Comment: @Yassir - First time I saw it, but since you had pretty much solved it in the question it wasn't that hard to tidy up the proof.